# Is it possible to automate plot_summs with a list of models?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to use a list of models to create a `jtools::plot_summs()` figure? I'm creating the models in batch and would like not to enter them into the function one by one:

Current workflow:

```
library(jtools)

tmp <- list(m1 = lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars),
            m2 = lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars))

plot_summs(tmp$m1, tmp$m2)
```

Desired workflow:

```
plot_summs(tmp)
```

Comment: Just guessing: `lapply(tmp, plot_summs)` ?

Comment: @zx8754, this plots each on it's own plot, not combined.

Comment: List as input feature is added by the author, see [GitHub issue #64](https://github.com/jacob-long/jtools/issues/64), so this `plot_summs(tmp)` now should work (dev version, soon cran version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you are looking for [do.call](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/do.call):
it takes a function to call, and a list of parameters, and "spreads" the parameters in the function, so `do.call(f, list(a, b, c))` is equivalent to `f(a, b, c)` . The advantage is that you don't need to hardcode the list of arguments.

```
do.call(plot_summs, tmp)
```

**edit:**
NB if your `tmp` list has name like in your examples, you might consider removing them for `plot_summs`, otherwise `do.call` will use name as the parameter name in the function.

for example,
`do.call(f, list(m1=1, m2=4))` is equivalent to `f(m1=1, m2=4)`
`do.call(f, list(1,4))` is equivalent to `f(1,4)`

so you can use `setNames` to remove the names of the list:

```
do.call(plot_summs, setNames(tmp, NULL))
```

Comment: edited to take in consideration the fact when the list is a named one but th names do not correspond to the actual parameters names.

Comment: Works a treat after your edit. Thanks. I keep forgetting `do.call` is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether it should be better to plot them using another package, because your models have different covariates.
In this case, I suggest you the following solution:

```
library(jtools)
library(dotwhisker)
tmp <- list(m1 = lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars),
            m2 = lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars))

plot_summs(tmp$m1, tmp$m2)
```

an alternative solution using the `dotwhisker` package

```
dwplot(tmp)
```

this is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List as input feature is added by the author, see [GitHub issue #64](https://github.com/jacob-long/jtools/issues/64), so below should work **^**, where *tmp* is a list:

```
plot_summs(tmp)
```

---

**^** dev version, soon cran version.